How do I intercept the openDefaultBrowser(url) call in Thunderbird?
Is there some kind of 'beforeLinkClick' event which can be canceled, on certain URLs? Or an option to rewrite the openDefaultBrowser(url) function, which I'm guessing gets called, when you click a link?
The end-goal is to develop a 'Link-Blocker' for emails opened in Thunderbird.
I already found out that there is a setting under network.protocol-handler.external-default to completely disable links, which is what I want for most links. Other links I want to whitelist via user-prompt.
